# Running ArcGIS webmap on Android Phone?

Tags: arcgis-online, maps, google, arcgis-android

I have a ArcGIS webmap ( http://lvrs.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Viewer/index.html?appid=a2756011923849659bc76ecd5ef7201c) and I am wondering how would I export this and actually be able to run this on google maps as a layer - so i can run it as an app - instead through the website. Also, the end game (this is for a fire department) then I would like to use it for navigation to an address. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Collector for Arcgis?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [ArcGIS SDK for Android](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/):

> Get the SDK that lets you build native mapping apps for Android
>   devices! Integrate a wide range of mapping and GIS tasks online or
>   offline, including editing, geocoding, routing, mapping, and data
>   visualization.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app for android that ESRI produced that can read a published map. I just downloaded it a minute ago.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.android.client&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Darcgis+android+app&pcampaignid=APPU_1Mx_VJavCcilNv3SgIgL

Perhaps that might work